# Conditional formating VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range of the data that i would like to use a conditional formationg for each row of my data, while the highest value has red color and lowest value has gree color. please see the example picture:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrV4s.png)

for that I have used the following code:

```
For k = 33 To  65
 
    With WBSim.Sheets("Country_1").Rows(k)

        .FormatConditions.AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=3
        .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
        .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).Type = _
                  xlConditionValueLowestValue
                    
    End With
```

But in the result the highest value has green color and the lowest value has Red color. Could you please let me know Hoe can i fix this problem?

Bests,
Parisa

Answer (score 1):

That the default setting when applying color scales, you need to add code to change the colors for the lowest/highest values.

This code will do it but you might want to play about with the colors to get exactly what you want.

```
Dim K As Long

    For K = 33 To 65

        With WBSim.Sheets("Country_1").Rows(K)
            .FormatConditions.AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=3
            With .FormatConditions(1)
                .SetFirstPriority
                With .ColorScaleCriteria(1)
                    .Type = xlConditionValueLowestValue
                    .FormatColor.Color = 5287936
                End With
                With .ColorScaleCriteria(2)
                    .Type = xlConditionValuePercentile
                    .FormatColor.Color = 8711167
                End With
                With .ColorScaleCriteria(3)
                    .Type = xlConditionValueHighestValue
                    .FormatColor.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                End With
            End With
        End With
        
    Next K
```